# App crashes on Android TV version 7+

Tags: android, android-tv, android-launcher, leanback

I have a mobile app that needs to run on Android TV. I don't have a TV to test it, so I'm trying over an emulator.

The app works just fine on Android versions < 7 (Marshmallow, Lollipop). But when I open it in the emulator with Nougat on it, the app keeps crashing and I get an error that says: "Leanback Launcher keeps stopping".

I've read that I should put some things in Manifest, but I'm confused, why is it working on Android versions  < 7?

This is my Manifest, so if you can take a quick look and advise me what to put inside to make it work?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="------">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:name="-----"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_2"
    android:label="@string/app_nameMain"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:label">
    <service android:name=".services.AutoUpdaterService" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.codepath.gcmquickstart" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".services.ZipaGcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".services.ZipaInstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">

        <!-- <intent-filter> -->
        <!-- <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /> -->
        <!-- </intent-filter> -->
    </service>

    <receiver android:name=".broadcasts.ConnectionChangeReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LauncherActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/App.Theme.Translucent"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AlarmTriggerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label=""
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/App.Theme.Translucent"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.LogInActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.BrowserManagerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/MyHomeCustomTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WizardActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.DeviceManagerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

    <service android:name="com.zipato.mqtt.MqttService" />

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.RegisterActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <!-- <activity -->
    <!-- android:name=".activities.ShakeSettingActivity" -->
    <!-- android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" -->
    <!-- android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/> -->
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.PasswordRecoveryActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CameraActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="CameraActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.DiscoveryActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ScreenShotActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MjpegStreamActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:label="CameraActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ShowVCMenu"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".activities.BrowserManagerActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ShowDialogActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/App.Theme.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WidgetConfigSwitch"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/App.Theme.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WidgetConfigLevel"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/App.Theme.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WidgetConfigRGBW"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/App.Theme.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WidgetConfigSecurity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/App.Theme.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WidgetConfigThermostat"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/App.Theme.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WidgetEventHandlerActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:label=""
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:theme="@style/App.Theme.Dialog"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.CreateWeatherActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcasts.ThermostatWidgetProvider"
        android:label="@string/zipato_thermostat_widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/thermostat_appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcasts.SecurityWidgetProvider"
        android:label="@string/zipato_security_widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/security_appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcasts.SwitchWidgetProvider"
        android:label="@string/zipato_switch_widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/switch_appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcasts.RGBWidgetProvider"
        android:label="@string/zipato_rgb_widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/rgb_appwiget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcasts.LevelWidgetProvider"
        android:label="@string/zipato_level_widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/level_appwidget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcasts.StartDevicesWidgetProvider"
        android:label="@string/zipato_start_dev_widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/start_dev_app_widget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcasts.StartRoomsWidgetProvider"
        android:label="@string/zipato_start_rooms_widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/start_room_app_widget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcasts.StartScenesWidgetProvider"
        android:label="@string/zipato_start_scenes_widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/start_scenes_app_widget_info" />
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".broadcasts.StartFavoriteWidgetProvider"
        android:label="@string/zipato_start_fav_widget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/start_fav_app_widget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".services.WidgetService"
        android:exported="false">

        <!-- <intent-filter> -->
        <!-- <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /> -->
        <!-- </intent-filter> -->
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WebViewActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AccountSettingsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AccountContactsActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.AccountContactsAddEdit"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityUsers"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityUsersEdit"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.ActivityGeneralSettings"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WalletActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.WalletWebViewActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.DeviceManActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.DeviceEndpointsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".activities.DeviceClusterEndpointActivity"
        android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme" />
</application>
```

LauncherActivity is my default launcher, should I add:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
```

inside its intent filter? Also, I assume I should add this permission also:

```
 <uses-feature android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="false" />
```

And this thing inside application tag:

```
android:banner="@drawable/banner"
```

Is there anything else or this is completely wrong?

Comment: Do you have access to a logcat?

Comment: Yes, you need log only from leanbacklauncher?

Comment: log cat will contain what the crash is.  We  need a bit more to go on for why things are crashing in order to help answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem has been addressed in this google forum [Why do Apps that stream live TV crash under Android 7.0 Nougat on Nexus 5x?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/hLVpgVPz6ic). In summary, the app you're running haven't been updated/not-ready for Nougat - higher versions of Android. Other apps, which supported Nougat, seemed to work fine.